# Is it possible to develop a meteor application as an embedded component on an existing page?

Tags: meteor

Of course this can be done using an iframe, but i'm looking for a solution where the application is injected in the dom on load, using all of the stylesheets and scripts that are already available on the page.

This is useful for websites that need a component with rather difficult requirements (like live push updates), that are available out of the box when using meteor.

I don't want to embed a meteor application inside of an iframe, because of the need of duplicating stylesheets of scripts on the main page.

Comment: Is there any improvements on this matter achieved in last 3 years? :) I'm trying to do the same thing nowadays.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out too but I think iframe is the best bet. It looks like you can dynamically add the same stylesheets if you want...and since most browsers have caching on it shouldn't add much to load time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192152/dynamically-inserting-stylesheet-into-iframe

Answer (score 1):

Because Meteor is a full-stack application framework, this won't be possible. Meteor isn't like a typical client-side javascript framework where you can just hook it into some other platform, it's a platform itself. So I would ask: what are you trying to do, and why do you think inserting Meteor into the page will help solve your problem?